# Navbar con bootstrap oculta la parte de arriba

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

quiero que el navbar baje cuando me desplego hacia abajo puse el navbar fixed-top, se desplega el navbar pero desde el comienzo se pone encima de unos botones que tengo, como podría hacerlo con boostrap. Imagen de como esta ahora
https://ibb.co/FbWY90c

```html
 <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light fixed-top">
    <!-- Left navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-  bars"></i></a>
      </li>
      <a onclick="cargar_conte('conte_princ','apr/view_apr.php')" class="nav-link">
      <i class="nav-icon fas fa-table"></i>
        <a href="index.php" class="nav-link">Inicio</a>
    </li>
      </li>
      </p>
            </a>
    </ul>
    <!-- Right navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <!-- Notifications Dropdown Menu -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="fullscreen" href="#" role="button">
          <i class="fas fa-expand-arrows-alt"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <span><?php echo $_SESSION['S_USU']?></span>
          <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
          <span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
        <a href="../controller/usuario/controlador_cerrar_sesion.php" class="dropdown-item">
        <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Cerrar Sesión
        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba agregando esto en tu CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Con ese atributo en el body estableces una distancia de 70 pixeles entre la parte superior de la ventana y el contenido del body, exceptuando el **nav** con el **fixed-top** que se superpone por encima.

Puedes modificar ese 70px por lo que quieras. Normalmente el **nav** son unos 50px pero puede variar según la versión de bootstrap o las modificaciones que le hayas realizado.

Comment: Me funciono pero el main siderbar se movió: https://ibb.co/6nk3zkZ

Comment: mmm... quizas debas ponerle tambien un fixed-top?  algo asi deberás hacer

Comment: masterguru, habrá otra forma de hacer lo q digo?

Comment: A ver, a ciegas poco puedo ayudar, no se como está codificado ese main sidebar. Se me ocurre que intentes ponerle un `padding-top: -70px` a ver si cuela, pero repito, si no lo veo no estoy seguro de lo que te estoy diciendo porque no puedo reproducir tu escenario y verificarlo

Comment: Código del siderbar https://jsfiddle.net/luiss1/7yf3hmq2/

Comment: Bueno, segun ese código estas usando AdminLTE, que tiene sus propias clases para todo eso, aparte de las de bootstrap. Quizas deberias mirarte sus clases y ver cual de ellas te puede ir mejor. En este enlace veo que muestran algunas: https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/layout.html.  Es más, esa propia página tiene una disposición parecida a la que quieres, pues mira su código fuente y las clases que usa para conseguirlo (quizas tendras que quitar lo del fixed-top de bootstrap y usar las suyas)

Comment: masterguru, consulta como seria para q se desplace 2 botones en solo movil https://ibb.co/g3rwxFP

Comment: No lo se, la verdad, supongo que con media queries... deberás hacer una nueva pregunta exponiendo el código de esos botones y su contexto para que alguien te sepa responder

Comment: Gracias masterguru.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta del navbar para que este fijo esta en la documentación de AdminLTE 3: https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/layout/fixed-topnav.html
Es agregar en el body: layout-navbar-fixed